# How to protect my Google account credentials on my Android phone?

Tags: security, gmail, google-account

Currently I use Gmail on my desktop with 2-step verification (by SMS) enabled and I consider it secure. Now I'm buying an Android phone and I'd like to check Gmail on it *sometimes*, but I don't want to save my password on the phone.

When my phone gets stolen or lost, the thief would gain access to all my Gmail data. I've heard Android uses Google account for a lot of things, like downloading apps from the store. Is there any way to set it up so that it doesn't store my password and asks for it every time I'd like to access mail?

I don't want to protect my phone entirely (with entering the PIN every time I use it etc.), as it's prepaid and I don't really have anything sensitive there.

Comment: Just use the browser to check your email.  If you use the built-in application your password will be saved since there are several applications that will interact with your Google account ( Google Play ) automatically.  Your lost phone problem is easily solved by using a pin to secure your phone.  Also you know your phone is lost so you can just change the account's password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a free service like [Android Lost](http://www.androidlost.com/), you can remotely control your phone from a web browser. You can wipe it, locate it on a map, read sms'es, take a picture remotely etc... to ease your concerns regarding security.

While not directly an answer to your question, it might be a viable solution.  Not storing your Google credentials on your Android smartphone and accessing Google services through the mobile web brower is not only very impractical, but also sort of defeats the purpose of a modern smartphone doesn't it ?

Comment: This and "APP Lock" application allowed me to do what I asked for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Google/Gmail account will be linked to the phone, you will not be asked to authenticate each time you access your mail, what you can do is this:

1. Enable two step authentication on your Google account
2. Download the [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2) app for your shiny new android phone
3. Pin/password protect your handset [using a pattern isn't the most secure method as it can easily be guessed]
4. [optional] use a password safe service like LastPass
5. Proffit???